# can't concanate var in import or require

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, cypress

I have

```
var appDir = 'D:/capitalVenture/cv/cv-cypress';
import LoginPage from 'D:/capitalVenture/cv/cv-cypress/src/test/js/cv/pages/LoginPage';
```

and want this

```
import LoginPage from '${appDir}/src/test/js/cv/pages/LoginPage';
```

or

```
var LoginPage = require('${appDir}/src/test/js/cv/pages/LoginPage');
```

but it not possible , any help will be appreciate

Comment: The `import` statement only allows *constant* strings. The `require()` mechanism is really a significantly different facility (though with similar intent of course).

Comment: `${...}` only has special meaning in template literals, not string literals.

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring the directory path prior to requiring it, using template strings.

```
var loginPagePath = `${appDir}/src/test/js/cv/pages/LoginPage`;
var LoginPage = require(loginPagePath);
```

Comment: it does not work, I get this error "Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'D:/capitalVenture/cv/cv-cypress/src/test/js/cv/pages/LoginPage'"

Comment: Are you sure that the module you are defining exists in that location? It looks like it's properly importing/required the defined path, but the module does not exist.

Comment: Thank for your help, yes the module existe and if i set the bsolute path doing this : import LoginPage from 'D:/capitalVenture/cv/cv-cypress/src/test/js/cv/pages/LoginPage',  it works